# AJAX only works when I'm logged as Admin

Tags: ajax

I want to make an AJAX request on every select value change to update the real value from database. I'm coding inside a shortcode on `functions.php`. I have a `select` element like this one below,

```
echo '<select name="changeValue" onchange="changeValue(' . $user->ID . ', this.options[this.selectedIndex])">'
```

At the end of the shortcode, I do:

```
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function changeValue(id, valueElement) {
            jQuery.post(
                "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>", 
                {
                    'action': 'update_value',
                    'data':  {
                        user_id: id,
                        value: valueElement.value
                    }
                }, 
                function(response){
                    console.log(response)
                }
            );
        }
    </script>
<?
}
add_shortcode('the_shortcode', 'the_shortcode');

function update_value() {
    $user_id = $_POST['data']['user_id'];
    $value= $_POST['data']['value'];
    echo $user_id . ' - ' . $empresa;

    //return update_user_meta($user_id , 'value', $value);
    wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_update_value', 'update_value' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_update_value', 'update_value' );
```

My code **works when I'm logged as Admin**. However if I'm logged as another user, `console.log(response)` returns the whole HTML page content. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Another difference is that when logged as Admin, `admin-ajax.php` returns `200 OK`, whereas when logged as a user it returns `302 Found`.

Answer (score 1):

What a type you work with response 
If you work with json

```
$.post( ajaxurl , data , function(res){
// your code 
},'json');
```

Remove wp_die() and replace with die()

Comment: Ok, I could use json, but why does my code work logged as Admin and not as user anyway?

Comment: @redraw post here response please to check.it

Comment: The response when logged as user is the full HTML page, without anything returned by my update_value() function

Comment: Problem Resolved !

Comment: It was solved! Actually handling the AJAX inside `front-page.php` because it was impossible by using `admin-ajax.php`. I'm still wondering why it isn't possible the "right" way. Besides that, thanks to @ahmed that helped me solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

When using `admin-ajax.php` the `admin_init` hook is fired, so many functions that run in the admin will also run when ajax is used. In this case there is some code locking non admin users out of the admin by redirecting them somewhere else. This could be part of your theme or coming from a plugin.

When the redirect fires it 'returns' the html of the homepage to your ajax request, which is why you see html instead of the response you expect.

The redirect would need to be modified to ignore ajax requests:

```
if ( ( ! current_user_can( 'level_5' ) ) && ( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != '/wp- admin/admin-ajax.php' ) )  {
    wp_redirect( site_url() );
}
```

You could also use the REST API instead of ajax to avoid this issue.